# How are Kaplan-Meier survival estimates calculated in survfit()?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm trying to perform Kaplan-Meier survival analysis for tree seedlings under different treatments. These seedlings were censused for mortality at nine times through the course of a 12-month experiment.

I have successfully obtained KM survival estimates for each treatment and time using survfit() in the survival package. However, I'm uncertain of how these survival estimates are being calculated; using the Kaplan-Meier survivor function described in Crawley's R Book (shown in the image below), I have done the analysis by hand and found that I'm not getting the same estimates.

[image: Kaplan-Meier estimator]

These are the survival estimates that I got using the equation above. (This is just for one treatment of my experiment).

[image: KM results - by hand]

When I use the function survfit(), these are the estimates that it returns:

```
    summary(FMACHN.fit)
    Call: survfit(formula = FMACHN ~ 1)

 time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
    4     54       3    0.944  0.0312        0.885        1.000
    5     45       4    0.860  0.0491        0.769        0.962
    6     36       4    0.765  0.0627        0.651        0.898
    7     27       4    0.652  0.0748        0.520        0.816
    8     18       4    0.507  0.0864        0.363        0.708
    9      9       5    0.225  0.0923        0.101        0.503
```

The only thing that I can think of that might be an issue is the format of the data that I have imported into the function. I have worked through several examples of KM analysis and I believe that I have structured my data correctly following these examples, so here's a peek at part of my data. "ID" is just the count of individuals in that treatment, "Time" is the time point in the experiment (in this case, it goes up to 9), and "Died" indicates the number of seedlings that died during that time period. This is just a longer form of the first table that I showed.

[image: KM data]

My code to analyze this was as follows:

```
library(survival)
#note that the object name "all" is what I called the dataset I imported, shown in the table above
FMACHN<-Surv(all$Time[all$Treatment=="FMACHN"], all$Alive[all$Treatment=="FMACHN"])
FMACHN.fit<-survfit(FMACHN~1)
summary(FMACHN.fit) 
#the result of this summary is listed in the code block above
```

If anyone can decipher what it is that R is doing differently in the Kaplan-Meier survivor function than I am doing by implementing the function by hand, I would greatly appreciate it! Or then again if it's something wrong with my data set up, that would be good to know too.

Thanks in advance! Please feel free to ask for clarification on anything - I know that was a long post!

Comment: You can inspect the definition with `body(survfit)`.

Comment: @nrussell I have tried that - unfortunately all it gives me is `{
    UseMethod("survfit", formula)
}`

Comment: So you keep going -- `body(survfit.formula)`.

Comment: If you only provide "pictures" of the data you will not get many tested solutions. Just looking at the example, however, I'm wondering how 3 deaths with 9 at risk gives you a 50% survival?